# Word 2010 caption has no number

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, numbering, caption

I am trying to place a Table caption above a table in Word 2010. It shows correctly in the insert caption box, but when it appears on the screen there is no number and no hyperlink colour. The word Table and the caption text appears, but no number? Why? How can I get my numbers to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the labels by pressing CTRL+A and then F9. If that does not work, show field codes by pressing ALT+F9 and see if the field structure is there. It should look something like this: `Table { SEQ Table \* ARABIC }`

Comment: I Have the same problem as the above. Showing field code does not work as caption is not being inserted as a field that can be updated...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Figures. To solve it, I inserted a second figure caption. When I did, Word assigned it the number 1. Then I used Alt+F9 to show field codes, copied and pasted the field code from the second caption to the first, and updated fields. I then had numbers (1 and 2) for both figures. You can delete the second one if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Missy's solution but the second caption did not work.

However,it got me thinking, so I added a table, inserted a caption, and the "Table" label worked with a number field.  I then inserted a "Figure" label to the same table and it worked.

I copied the "figure" number field to the other figure captions that did not work before and they adjusted the numbering themselves.  Automatic numbering for the Figure labels worked automatically afterwards.